# Alternative to the compilation error with the service of jcenter()

Tags: android, react-native

Good morning, any of you have had a problem currently with the modification of android with respect to jcenter() in android developments with react native? I have an application under these developments and it has been a little difficult to run it because it presents me with such problems, try to place according to the following order google(), mavencentral(), jcenter() (that was a possible solution that appeared to me in the research that I have been able to perform) in the different files of build.gradle and where the call is made and still does not give me a solution, does anyone know any other way that has worked.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It also need more code such as your `build.gradle` (you can add it in tag too)